# How to Edit .htaccess File

Tags: php, .htaccess

Right now i have htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"

</IfModule>
```

And I wanted to add some code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Where I can Put this code
Inside  or Outside.Please Suggest/guide me Proper Solution.

Comment: you already have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.divineworkspot.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.divineworkspot.com/$1 [L,R=301]`

Comment: IT is correct to add inside th ifmodule?

Comment: you have to write it there

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should do

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</ifModule>
```

see [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/htaccess-for-all/) for reference

also you can check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-htaccess-file) for more detail on `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Open a new IfModule under your `mod_expires`. You may refer to [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules)

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
// your code
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Or Just

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 // your code
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IfModule` checks if the given module is installed and is active. In your example file, its checking if `mod_expires.c` module exists. If yes do the stuff inside the tag.

Apache rewrites are handled by `mod_rewrite.c` apache module. So you should do:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

You can get away by removing the tags completely. If there were no tags and you dont have `mod_rewrite` installed, apache will error out. `IfModule` gracefully ignores line inside the tag if the required apache module doesn't exist.